Estimation of the absolute value of an infinite sum by its coefficient
I got this problem from a complex funtion, but it now has little to do with the complex analysis.
$$\Theta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}s^{2n}$$
I already have:
$$c_1^n\frac{(\ln n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\leq |a_{2n}|\leq c_2^n\frac{(\ln 2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
I want to confirm:
$$|\Theta(s)|=O(s^{cs})$$
I'm not familiar with the estimation of the series, could anyone provide any solutions or thoughts?

Look up §2.3 of Riemann's zeta function by H. M. Edwards.

I am not sure that your estimate is correct as if say $a_{2n}=100\frac{(\ln n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ it is easily seen that for $s_n=2n/\log (2n)$ one has $\log \Theta(s_n) \ge 20en(1+o(1))=10(1+o(1))e s_n\log s_n$ by Stirling using just the $a_{2n}$ term so $\Theta(s_n) \ge s_n^{(10e-\epsilon)s_n}$ so you need an $O(s^{cs})$ there; then you can show that type of inequality (for $s >0$) by looking at $2n/\log n>10s$ and $2n/\log n \le 10 s$ separately and in the first case terms are exponentially small, while in the second you can estimate $\log 2n$ by $\log s$ etc
